# How show an slider with links in each image as background in html?

Tags: html, css

I wanna replace a background image with a slider with images that navigate to different views, without removing the text, location, and button that appear above the section.

I need each image to have a headline with a link to other view, with arrows to move forward or backward.

My page with a background image of moais and the text above it.

[image]

The code of my index.html

```css
.hero {
  background-image: url(../img/Moais.jpg);
  /*BACKGROUND IMAGE*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 450px;
  /* padding: 20px; */
  position: relative;
}

.contenido-hero {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /*a = transparencia*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*Centrar verticalmente*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.contenido-hero h2,
.contenido-hero p {
  color: var(--blanco);
}

.ubicacion {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.boton {
  background-color: var(--secundario);
  color: var(--blanco);
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
}

@media(min-width: 480px) {
  /*Celular*/
  .boton {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="contenido-hero">
    <h2>Diseño y desarrollo web <span>freelancer</span></h2>
    <div class="ubicacion">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-map-pin" width="88" height="88" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#ffbf00" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <circle cx="12" cy="11" r="3" />
                <path d="M17.657 16.657l-4.243 4.243a2 2 0 0 1 -2.827 0l-4.244 -4.243a8 8 0 1 1 11.314 0z" />
            </svg>
      <p>Hanga Roa, Rapa Nui, Valparaíso</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="boton">Contactar</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Any suggestion what should I do? Do I need to use other languages? First of all, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with this way

```
#mydiv{ animation: changeBg 1s infinite; width:500px; height:500px; }

@keyframes changeBg{
   0%,100% {background-image: url("https://example.com/example.png");}
   25% {background-image: url("https://example.com/example2.png");}
   50% {background-image: url("https://example.com/example3.png");}
   75% {background-image: url("https://example.com/example4.png");}
}

<div id='mydiv'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Although I don't know how to put the titles to each image, to see the text, nor how to put arrows ,I tried to place text on each image with content: 
`0%,100% {
    background-image: url("/assets/img/noticias/noticiaecoladrillos.jpg");
    content: "Invernadero en base a ecoladrillos";
  }` but don't works